# Is it true $E(E(X|Y)|Z)=E(E(X|Y,Z)|Z)$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Intuitively I think this is true since given more information about $Z$ in the inner expectation seems to have no effect. But with Adam's law, we see that this would imply $E(E(X|Y)|Z)=E(E(X|Y,Z)|Z)=E(X|Z)$, which I'm not quite sure. Can someone confirm this is indeed true and provide a proof or a source of proof? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true.

First, recall the law of iterated expectations:
$$E(E(X|Y))=E(X)$$
Consider the expression $E(E(X|Y,Z)|Z)$. Given $Y=y,Z=z$ the inner expectation is evaluated in the conditional universe where $Y=y,Z=z$; the outer expectation averages over all $Y=y$ given $Z=z$, and we end up with the law of iterated expectations in the conditional universe $Z=z$
$$E(E(X|Y,Z=z)|Z=z)=E(X|Z=z)$$
or in r.v. notation
$$E(E(X|Y,Z)|Z)=E(X|Z)$$
On the other hand, the expression $E(E(X|Y)|Z)$ is something different. Given $Y=y,Z=z$ the inner expectation is evaluated in the conditional universe where $Y=y$, and there is no reason for
$$E(E(X|Y)|Z=z)\overset{?}{=}E(X|Z=z)$$
to be true. For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $E(X|Y)=E(X)=constant$, and we end up with
$$E(X)\overset{?}{=}E(X|Z=z)$$
which cannot be generally true.

Comment: sorry that i might have a basic misunderstanding...  when you say $X$ and $Y$ are independent, that would be independence within the conditional universe $Z=z$, right?  in this universe, $E(X|Y)=E(X)=constant$ but the constant depends on $z$, right?

Comment: @antkam no, if $X$ and $Y$ are unconditionally independent; then $E(X|Y)=E(X)$ is just a (constant) number, and since a constant is independent from  anything $E(E(X)|Z=z)=E(E(X))=E(X)$

Comment: but $Y$ can be independent of everything else, while $X$ and $Z$ are still dependent...  say $X$ and $Y$ are two independent 0-1 fair-coin-flips, but $Z=X$.  Then $E(X|Y)=0.5$ but shouldnt $E(E(X|Y)|Z=z) = z$ instead?

Comment: @antkam then $E(E(X|Y)|Z=z) = 0.5$. Conditioning on $Z=z$ does not affect the inner expectation, and given $X$ and $Y$ are independent does not affect the outer expectation too.

Comment: "Conditioning on Z=z does not affect the inner expectation" -- i guess that's the part i dont agree with, but then, my understanding of iterated expectations is rather informal (to say the least)...

Comment: @antkam just be careful with notation; $E(X|Y)$ is a fully defined expression, and conditioning on $Z$ in the expression $E(E(X|Y)|Z)$ is not related to the inner $E(X|Y)$.

Comment: OK i think i see your point...  you're saying $E(X|Y)$ is a fully defined function of $y$, and in my example, that function is the constant $0.5$.  in fact if i may generalize what you're saying, you would say $E(X|X=1) = 1$ but $E(E(X)|X=1)=0.5$, right?

Comment: @antkam exactly, you hit the nail :)